# Break points aspx pages

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008, debugging

How do you set a break points in server tags in .aspx pages. e.g.

```
<%   dim breakhere =new object() %>
```

The web application is running in debug mode with the `<compilation debug="true" ...` in the web.config. But the page says:

> The break point will not currently be
>   hit. No symbols have been loaded for
>   this document.

Is there anything else i need to set?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

instead of setting the breakpoint directly, you could use

```
<%  System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();

    // more code here...

     %>
```

Maybe a better suggestion though is to not put inline code in your markup - instead put it in a method in the code-behind file, and then call that method from your markup.  In your method in the code-behind, you can use the breakpoints as you normally would.

Answer (score -1):

I havent tried this myself but in ASP (VBScript) you can inject a STOP statement and that will trigger the IDE to break on that line

Example

```
<%
STOP
Dim o as Object = new Object()
%>
```

HTH