# VS 2012 can't set breakpoints in Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, debugging, razor

When trying to set a breakpoint in a razor view I get the message "This is not a valid location for a breakpoint".

Breakpoints work in JS and everywhere else they're supposed to.
Intellisense and auto-complete also work in Razor.

Using
- VS 2012 Update 4
- .Net Framework 4.5.1
- MVC 5.1

Sample Code

```
<div>
@{ 
var testString = string.Empty;
}
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure it's breakable code? Sometimes VS is "smart" and won't let you set a breakpoint if there is nothing there to break on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's is another SO problem that describes the issue I'm having and downloading the update from MS fixed it.

[This is not a valid location for a breakpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13967675/this-is-not-a-valid-location-for-a-breakpoint)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's breakable code? Sometimes VS is "smart" and won't let you set a breakpoint if there is nothing there to break on.

Have you tried a larger block of code?  Define the variable, assign a different value, do another op on it.  Then set the breakpoint somewhere at the end or the middle.

Comment: I have tried a lot of different pages with the same result. Even with the very basic sample code it won't budge. I have also tried to move the block around, inline, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same, and I resolved it as to restart the Visual studio,
What i think this happens when you did changes with name of your view respectively with controller and scaffolding needs to be rerun again.so after restart the system it automatically give me the changes.